# How do I enter hibernation mode from the Windows lock screen?

Tags: windows-vista, security

When you lock the desktop, there is no option to shut down, reboot, or to put the computer in hibernation mode. It is only after you unlock the desktop that you can go to the start menu and click the button for hibernation or the arrow button next to it for more options. Now, is there a way to enter hibernation mode while still viewing the lock screen?

Whenever I leave the computer unattended I usually press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock my desktop. When I come back I enter my password and enter back into desktop. But my concern is that if I put the computer in hibernation mode to save energy, and I leave it unattended, then all it takes for anyone is to just move the mouse and they get to my desktop.

**Update:**
I thought I would share with you what the Power Options dialog looks like on my side.

[image: Power Options (Energialternativ)]

You see that there are two entries titled "Viloläge". Those are called Hibernation in English. But why do I have two of them?... I also have two of them in the two drop-down menus below this one.

**Update 2:**
Just for future reference, this is where you start off.
[image: Energialternativ]

Then you pick the recommended option to require a password on wake-up.

[image: Energialternativ]

This can also be done from the Power Options dialog box, as shown by Avirk.

Comment: You can do it by setting the power option. When you press the Power button it will be Hibernate or Sleep as you will set them.

Comment: I'm not following... when I set what where? I have no such option on the start menu, or in the Power Options dialog. Please give me a step by step instruction.

Comment: "Power Options" should definitely have two options: 1) "When power button is pressed: Hibernate", 2) "Prompt for password on resume" (though they'll be worded a bit differently)

Comment: `Control Panel>Power options>change plan settings>Change advance power settings` and in this dialog `Power Button and Lid` option will solve this.

Comment: I tell you, I don't have the "prompt for password on resume" option, or anything similar. What is the exact wording here? What's the name of this option? Can you please post a screenshot of this dialog box? My Windows is in Swedish, and I am suspecting a bad translation or something, because I have duplicate entries titled "Viloläge" (Hibernation in English).

Comment: Ok I'll post an answer for this.

Comment: Any idea why I have two entries titled Hibernation (Viloläge)? I think one of them is in fact Hibernation, and the other is Sleep. But when you give them the same name you can't really tell them apart. So much for localizing Windows to other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the energy settings, there is a linked option on the upper left of the window for making the pc ask for the password when it wakes up. Therefore, you could just put it to sleep and it will be locked automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the **Control Panel** by clicking on Start menu and now open the **Power Options** from there. Now whatever your power plan is hit the option **Change Plan Settings** a window will appear as shown below

[image]

[image]

Now first option will be prompt you to whether you want to prompt for password on wakeup or not.

[image]

In the same window scroll down and you will find the option **`Power Button and Lid`**

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's not really in the "Power buttons and lid" menu. It is located on the top, but this is a two step process. To put the computer in hibernation by pressing the power button you need to change the action for that button, and to require a password you need to set that to Yes. Thank you!